# How do I replace a symlink with the actual file?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I want to remove the symlink and instead insert the file it links to, if possible all with one command so I can have it as an "External Tool" in phpStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cp --remove-destination "$(readlink <symlink>)" <symlink>
```

<sup>Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35027</sup>

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it didn't work but it turns out that it was because the links where copied and didn't point to the right place anymore. But I was confused and thought it was something with bash

Comment: How do I get this to work for all symlinks in a directory?  Find complains about `illegal option -t` whenever I put it in a loop.

Comment: @cjm This should work fine with find. Are you missing the path as an argument to find? What's your exact find command?

Comment: @grgarside I was missing the path as my find argument.  Now my problem is that cp is getting whiny about `illegal option -- -` instead of recognizing `--remove-destination` as a valid option.  Command is `for f in (find . -type l); cp --remove-destination "(readlink $f)" $f;end;`; shell is fish.  It complains about the illegal option whether or not the `(readlink $f)` is quoted or not.

Comment: @cjm You're missing a ‘$’ before the open bracket before readlink (should be `"$(readlink`). Also why are you using the shell to do the loop? `find . -type l -exec cp --remove-destination "$(readlink {})" {} \;`

Comment: I was using the shell for looping based off [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26298571/5544691).  It seems that `--remove-destination` doesn't work in Mac OS, since everything I try ends with `cp: illegal option -- -`

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS' `cp` doesn't have the `--remove-destination` parameter, you have a couple options:

- Install GNU `cp`

  ```
  brew install coreutils
  ```

  And then follow the step in [grg's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/154011/22772) (note that GNU `cp` is installed as `gcp`)

  ```
  gcp -a --remove-destination "$(readlink <symlink>)" "<symlink>"
  ```
- Or remove the symlink first, e.g.

  ```
  sourcefile=$(readlink "<symlink>"); rm "<symlink>" && cp -a "$sourcefile" "<symlink>"
  ```